# How to query a pandas DataFrame using an array of tuples ?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following structure:

[image: sample data frame image]

And I have an array of tuples

`arr_tuples = [(0,3),(1,1),(1,3),(2,1)]`

Each tuple in the array represent the row and column index of the above dataframe respectively.

I can find all the values in the data frame for the indices in `arr_tuples` using for loop like this:

```
value_array = []
for item in arr_tuples:
    row = item[0]
    col = item[1]
    value = df.iloc[row,col] # I also tried df.get_value here with similar result 
    value_array.append(value)
```

But this seems to be a very slow method. If there are a lot of tuples in my `arr_tuples`, this will take a long time.

Is there a better and faster way to achieve the same ? 
Is there any way in pandas where I can use a list/array of tuples (containing row and column index) to get values in a dataframe ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.lookup` with some `zip` and unpacking trickery

```
df.lookup(*zip(*arr_tuples))

array([ 4,  5,  7, 12])
```

---

- `list(zip(*arr_tuples))` creates two tuples out of the list of tuples

  ```
  [(0, 1, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3, 1)]
  ```
- Well that's perfect because the first tuple are indices and the second are columns.  That's what `pd.DataFrame.lookup` accepts as arguments.  So if I unpack those, it'll just work

  ```
  df.lookup(*zip(*arr_tuples))

  array([ 4,  5,  7, 12])
  ```

Comment: Great solution.  Congrats on the hundo.

Comment: Thank you and thank you.  T-shirt, mug, and stickers incoming

Comment: I check old emails and email was in one lost email folder from 15 May ;)

Comment: @pirsquared : Thanks. That seems to be what we are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be faster if you make `arr_tuples` into a `Series`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {0:[1,4,11,14],1:[2,5,12,5],2:[3,6,13,6],3:[4,7,14,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
arr_tuples = [(0,3),(1,1),(1,3),(2,1)]

s = pd.Series(arr_tuples)
value_array = s.apply(lambda (x,y): df.iloc[x,y])

value_array
0     4
1     5
2     7
3    12
dtype: int64
```